# Mediawiki MobileFrontend: Stop collapsing sections by default

Tags: jquery-mobile, mediawiki

Collapsed sections example:

[image]

The default of Mediawiki's Mobilefrontend is that sections are collapsed by default, they are uncollapsed when the user clicks on the section title.

I want to change it so that the uncollapsedness is the default.

**What I have tried:**

1. In all of MobileFrontend files, I found that "collaps" exists in these (and only these) files

   ```
   MobileFrontend\javascripts\common\PageApi.js
   MobileFrontend\less\common\enwp.less
   MobileFrontend\less=common\reset.less
   ```

   But I am unsure if these are related with what I try to do.
2. I tried to apply the guidelines in Manual:Collapsible_elements of mediawiki to those three files but it didn't work.
3. I searched "expandablesections" using 'Find in files' of Notepad++.

   Then I found

   ```
   MobileFrontend\includes\api\ApiParseExtender.php
    Line 82:   $mf->enableExpandableSections( !$params['mainpage'] );
   MobileFrontend\includes\formatters\MobileFormatter.php
    Line 23:   protected $expandableSections = false;
    Line 64: $formatter->enableExpandableSections( !$isMainPage && !$isSpecialPage );
    Line 89:   public function enableExpandableSections( $flag = true ) {
    Line 90:       $this->expandableSections = $flag;
   MobileFrontend\includes\formatters\MobileFormatterHTML.php
    Line 24:       if ( $this->expandableSections ) {
   MobileFrontend\tests\MobileFormatterTest.php
    Line 24:       $mf->enableExpandableSections();
   ```
4. I tried changing

   ```
   $expandableSections = false;
   ```

   to

   ```
   $expandableSections = true;
   ```

   but it didn't make the sections uncollapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LocalSettings.php: `$wgMFCollapseSectionsByDefault = false;`